# Relogin in apple services after Apple ID password is changed

Tags: macos, apple-id

Is it necessary to relogin (logout and login again) in apple services on MacOS after Apple ID password has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary but it's a good practice.  Some services will not work because they can no longer log-in.

The services you use for iCloud, iTunes, etc, will be trying to log-in using an old password.  That will fail and it will prompt you for your password.  This will keep happening until you enter the correct password.

If you want to bypass all those notifications you can log-out and then log-in again with your updated credentials.

Comment: I noticed that iTunes, App Store prompted for a new password. But what about iMessage, FaceTime, and iCloud in system preferences? Non of it asks to reenter a password.

Comment: It will when it tries to re-authenticate with the servers (I'll update my answer, I just noticed it was a bit misleading).  You can avoid all that by logging out and logging back in.  I just had to do this a few weeks ago and that's what happened to me.